# How do I answer my GSM module phone call in x360 1030 G2 with ubuntu 19.10

Tags: hp, 19.10

My Laptop [x360 1030 G2](https://store.hp.com/us/en/tech-takes/hp-elitebook-x360-1030-g2-laptop-complete-review). It has features like using GSM module, we can call. Ubuntu recognises the sim slot. When I call my phone number it is ringing however I could not get the call in my machine

Answer (score 0):

If your cellphone provider does not provide you with a 'client' app for 'Voice Over IP' to answer the phone, here's a [list of some of those clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_VoIP_software#Desktop_applications): You will want one which supports Ubuntu Linux. Click on the up/down arrowheads in the second column, 'Operating systems' to sort for Linux.